# Can't get value from query string cordova windows phone

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How get value from query string  index.html#id=1&name=Lionel

below code work when set ? instead # in above link.

example:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's a simple answer to your problem. let's say the url is `www.awsomepage.dev?foo=bar&baz#foobar` the command `location.search` will return `?foo=bar&baz` since that's the `search` part. To access the hashtag data you have to use `location.hash` which will return `#foobar`.

For your code to work with a `#`, you should replace

```
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
```

by

```
var regex = new RegExp("[\\#&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.hash);
```

What have I changed:
First: in your regex you check for `?` and `&` as start. You'll obviously have to change it to `#` and `&`.
Second: change `location.search` to `location.hash` since you are targeting the hash.

Hope that helps. For further readings, I'd reccomment to take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location